# Is it possible to have Doxygen directly show the only module when clicking the Modules tab?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

Consider the following single-file project.

```
/** \defgroup api Public API */

/**
 * This is foo and bar together.
 * \ingroup api
 */
void foobar() {
    // Nothing here to see.
}
```

In the directory containing this file, I run the following commands.

```
doxygen -g
doxygen Doxyfile
```

When I open `html/index.html`, I see three tabs titled `Main Page`, `Modules`, and `Files` respectively.

If I click on `Modules`, I see a list of all modules, which contains only a single module. I must then click on the module name to see the documentation for the module.

**Does there exist an option in Doxygen which allows me to avoid the final click?**

That is, if I have only one group in my project, I would like the generated HTML to only require clicking on the `Modules` tab to show the one group.

I realize that I can manually edit the generated html, but I am looking for in-doxygen ways to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by changing the layout file. First generate a layout file using

```
doxygen -l
```

then in your Doxyfile set

```
LAYOUT_FILE = DoxygenLayout.xml
```

Now edit the DoxygenLayout file and replace

```
<tab type="modules" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
```

with

```
<tab type="user" visible="yes" url="@ref api" title="API" intro=""/>
```

Can find more info on doxygen layout file here: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout