# How do I specify a Markdown file as another tab in Doxygen?

Tags: documentation, markdown, doxygen, documentation-generation

Consider a project that has the following two files. Note that `OtherTab.md` lives in a subdirectory.

#### README.md

```
# This is the main page.

Main Page contents.
```

#### wiki/OtherTab.md

```
# This is another tab

Contents for another tab.
```

Now, I run `Doxygen -g` to generate a `Doxyfile`. I add the following lines to the `Doxyfile`.

```
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md
INPUT                  = . wiki
```

I would like to add a tab called `Wiki` next to the `Main Page` tab, which points at the file `wiki/OtherTab.md`.

**How might I accomplish this?**

I have looked [this question](https://superuser.com/a/685829/109158), and [this documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html), but neither addresses the question of how to actually create a new tab in Doxygen and point it at the html generated by processing a particular Markdown file.

Additionally, I have attempted to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41062979/391161) to my previous question, but was not sure what to put in the `url` attribute of the `tab` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appear some amount of experimentation, it appears that there is a standard transformation that is applied to the names of Markdown files.

Thus, the following steps will create a new tab pointing at the Markdown file.

1. Generate a layout file with `doxygen -l`.
2. In the Doxyfile set `LAYOUT_FILE = DoxygenLayout.xml`.
3. In the `DoxygenLayout.xml` file, add the following tab.

   ```
   <tab type="user" visible="yes" url="md_wiki_OtherTab.html"  title="Wiki"/>
   ```

The standard filename transformation is `md_{path_to_markdown_without_extension}.html`.